# prime dividing a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

If $p$ is a prime satisfying  $n<p<2n$, show that $\binom{2n}{n}\equiv 0\mod p$.

See that $$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}=\frac{2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)\cdots (n+1)}{n\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$$

$p$ lies between $n$ and $2n$ so $p$ divides $2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)\cdots (n+1)$.

Now, denominator has $2n$ so, it cancels with $2n$ in numerator leaving

\begin{align}
  \frac{(2n-1)\cdot (2n-2)\cdots (n+1)}{(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot 1} &=
\frac{(2n-1)\cdot 2(n-1)\cdots (n+1)}{(n-1)\cdots 3\cdot 1} \\[0.3cm]
  &= \frac{(2n-1)\cdot 2\cdot (2n-3)\cdot 2\cdots (n+1)}{(n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 1}
\end{align}

I am not very sure how to proceed..

I see that $n-2$ in the denominator gets cancelled with $2n-4$ in the numerator and so on... As $p$ is already out of business, there is no $p$ and we are cancelling $2(n-k)$ so they are not primes...

Comment: Both p are cancelled so why bother now

Comment: @ArchisWelankar : How do you know remaining is an integer.. ?

Comment: A binomial coefficient is always an integer.

Comment: Since $p<2n$ we see that $p$ divides $(2n)!$.  Since $p>n$ we see that $p$ does not divide $n!$.  Thus $p$ divides the numerator, but not the denominator.

Comment: a binomial coefficient is always an integer.. agreed but we are not having full binomial coefficient.. one factor is removed from numerator.. @Peter

Comment: @lulu You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: We have $(2n)!=\binom{2n}{n}n!n!$. Note now that $p$ divides $(2n)!$ but does not divide $n!$, and use Euclid's Lemma. In divisibility arguments, fractions can be confusing, and a "flat" equation like $(2n)!=\dots$ is more useful.

Comment: I will try that as well @AndréNicolas :)

Comment: One book called this the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic : For non-zero integers $a,b,c,$ if $c|a b$ and $\gcd (c,a)=1$ then $c|b.$  Apply this with $c=n!,\; a=p,\; b=[\;\prod_{j=n+1}^{p-1}j\;] \cdot [\;\prod_{j=p+1}^{2 n}j\;].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easiest to use the fact from number theory that $p\mid ab$ implies $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.  In this case let $a={2n\choose n}$ and $b=n!n!$.  Then $ab=(2n)!$ which is divisible by any $p$ less than $2n$, while $b$ is not divisible by any $p$ greater than $n$.

Comment: No more questions on this... Pretty clear..